# next data is not loading in my pagination

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

So, I have been making a User Directory Website using react and redux. Now I want to do a pagination of 20users per page from my local json file and I got the first 20 page but when I click on next button the next page doesn't load .

This is my userList.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setUsers } from '../store/userSlice';
import UserCard from './UserCard';
import Pagination from './Pagination';
import myData from '../data/heliverse_mock_data.json';

const UserList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users.users);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const usersPerPage = 20;
  const domainFilter = useSelector((state) => state.users.domainFilter);
  const genderFilter = useSelector((state) => state.users.genderFilter);
  const availabilityFilter = useSelector((state) => state.users.availabilityFilter);
  const searchQuery = useSelector((state) => state.users.searchQuery);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setUsers(myData));
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };

  

  const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => {
    const fullName = user.first_name + user.last_name;
    let filterCondition = true;

    if (domainFilter && domainFilter !== 'All Domains' && user.domain !== domainFilter) {
      filterCondition = false;
    }
    if (genderFilter && genderFilter !== 'All Genders' && user.gender !== genderFilter) {
      filterCondition = false;
    }
    if (
      availabilityFilter &&
      availabilityFilter !== 'Both' &&
      user.available !== (availabilityFilter === 'Yes')
    ) {
      filterCondition = false;
    }
    if (searchQuery && !fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
      filterCondition = false;
    }

    return filterCondition;
  });

  const totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredUsers.length / usersPerPage);
  const indexOfLastUser = currentPage * usersPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstUser = indexOfLastUser - usersPerPage;
  const currentUsers = filteredUsers.slice(indexOfFirstUser, indexOfLastUser);

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-4 mt-8">
      {currentUsers.map((user) => (
        <UserCard key={user.id} user={user} />
      ))}
        
      <Pagination
        totalPages={totalPages}
        currentPage={currentPage}
        onPageChange={(page) => handlePageChange(page)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

this is my pagination.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setPaginationPage } from '../store/userSlice';

const Pagination = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentPage = useSelector((state) => state.users.paginationPage);
  const totalPages = useSelector((state) => state.users.totalPages);

  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    dispatch(setPaginationPage(page));
  };

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    if (currentPage < totalPages) {
      handlePageChange(currentPage + 1);
      console.log("h")
    }
  };

  const handlePreviousPage = () => {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
      handlePageChange(currentPage - 1);
    }
  };

  const renderPaginationLinks = () => {
    const links = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      links.push(
        <button
          key={i}
          className={`px-4 py-2 rounded-md ${
            i === currentPage ? 'bg-blue-500 text-white' : 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-800'
          }`}
          onClick={() => handlePageChange(i)}
        >
          {i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return links;
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center">
      <button
        onClick={handlePreviousPage}
        disabled={currentPage === 1}
        className={`px-4 py-2 rounded-md mr-2 ${
          currentPage === 1 ? 'bg-gray-300 cursor-not-allowed' : 'bg-blue-500 text-white'
        }`}
      >
        Previous
      </button>
      {renderPaginationLinks()}
      <button
        onClick={handleNextPage}
        disabled={currentPage === totalPages}
        className={`px-4 py-2 rounded-md ml-2 ${
          currentPage === totalPages ? 'bg-gray-300 cursor-not-allowed' : 'bg-blue-500 text-white'
        }`}
      >
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```

this is my redux's store userSlice.jsx

```
import { configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


const initialState = {
    users: [],
    searchQuery: '',
    domainFilter: '',
    genderFilter: '',
    availabilityFilter: '',
    paginationPage: 1,
    teamMembers: [],
    totalPages:26
};



const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'users',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUsers: (state, action) => {
            state.users = action.payload;
        },
        setSearchQuery: (state, action) => {
            state.searchQuery = action.payload
        },
        setDomainFilter: (state, action) => {
            state.domainFilter = action.payload
        },
        setGenderFilter: (state, action) => {
            state.genderFilter = action.payload;
        },
        setAvailabilityFilter: (state, action) => {
            state.availabilityFilter = action.payload
        },
        setPaginationPage: (state, action) => {
            state.paginationPage = action.payload
        },
        addToTeam: (state, action) => {
            state.teamMembers.push(action.payload)
        },
        removeFromTeam: (state, action) => {
            state.teamMembers = state.teamMembers.filter(
                (user) => user.id !== action.payload
            )
        }
    },
    
})



const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        users: userSlice.reducer
    },
});

export const { setUsers, setSearchQuery, setDomainFilter, setGenderFilter, setAvailabilityFilter, setPaginationPage , addToTeam , removeFromTeam} = userSlice.actions

export default store;
```

I tried console logging the handleNextPage in pagination.jsx thinking there might be problem in currentPage or totalPages but this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're managing the current page state in two places: once in your `UserList` component and again in your Redux store. This could be causing the issue.

When you click the next button, you're updating the `paginationPage` in the Redux store, but the `currentPage` in the `UserList` component stays the same, so you're seeing the same users.

Here's a suggestion: why not remove the local `currentPage` state from the `UserList` component and use the paginationPage from the Redux store instead? You can do this by replacing `const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);` with `const currentPage = useSelector((state) => state.users.paginationPage)`; in your `UserList` component.

And in your `handlePageChange` function, you can dispatch the `setPaginationPage` action instead of setting the local state. This way, both your UserList and Pagination components will be using and updating the same state in the Redux store, and your pagination should work as expected.